# Angular Electron os.platform() is not a function

Tags: angular, electron

When `npm start`  I'm getting this error my Electron 17.1 with Angular 13 app
from the code :

```
import os from 'os';
....
const platform = os.platform();
```

on my ElectronJS 17.1 with Angular 13 app.